# Improve this query with use of union

Tags: php, mysql

This query gives an error if subquery return more than 1 row. I separated the queries and use `mysqli_multi_query()`, but both queries data is displayed in two tables.

So I decided to make the one query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT category , 
      (SELECT COUNT(products.name)
       FROM products
       where category_id=categories.id
      ) AS total_products,
      ( 
          SELECT SUM(quantity)  FROM productstock a
          LEFT JOIN products b ON a.product_id=b.id
          LEFT JOIN categories c ON b.category_id=c.id
          where c.deleted=0 
          GROUP BY category_id
      ) AS available_stock, 
      SUM(product_qty*orignalCost) AS SaleWise_cost,
      SUM(product_qty*saleprice) AS SaleWise_price,
      SUM(product_qty*saleprice) AS total_sale , 
      SUM((product_qty*saleprice)-(product_qty*orignalCost)) AS profit
FROM categories
INNER JOIN products ON  categories.id =  products.category_id
INNER JOIN sales ON  sales.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN productstock ON  productstock.product_id = products.id
WHERE categories.deleted=0
GROUP BY category_id
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? How is this related to PHP?

Comment: You probably don't want the inner join inside the subquery. See [Jeff's post on visualizing joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for referrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As available stock is corelated subquery so joining condition must be added in where clause inside subquery. please check this pseudocode

```
( 
          SELECT SUM(quantity)  FROM productstock a
          LEFT JOIN products b ON a.product_id=b.id
          LEFT JOIN categories c ON b.category_id=c.id
          where c.deleted=0  AND b.category_id = categories.id
      ) AS available_stock
```

Another way

```
(SELECT SUM(quantity)  
 FROM products b
 INNER JOIN productstock a 
         ON b.id = a.product_id
        AND b.id = products.id
        AND b.category_id = categories.id) AS available_stock
```

Comment: Hi @BakhtawarAshraf please check this pseudocode

Comment: Welcome @BakhtawarAshraf. As GROUP BY use in query so try to avoid DISTINCT clause. Please mark as accepted if this answer is helped you.